# Some HTML contents don't exist in the results when printing BeautifulSoup Response with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a Udemy course price, but when I print the response content, the price and its whole div seem to be not present in the result, what's the reason for this?

Here's the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

    
url = "https://www.udemy.com/course/python-for-data-science-and-machine-learning-bootcamp/"
session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)

response = session.get(url)
udemy_ML = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(udemy_ML, "html.parser")
print(soup.contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

That page contains a bit of JavaScript that goes and gets the price dynamically.  Since the `requests` library doesn't interpret (much less execute) JavaScript, the price is not in the `response.content` string.

You can confirm this by loading the page in your browser, and doing "view source", then searching for the price in the text.  It won't be there.

To answer your next question ("how do I make this work?"), you'll have to find something that is capable of interpreting and executing JavaScript.  I know Selenium gets mentioned a lot.